# Is there an Atlassian stash plugin to handle git notes?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, git-notes

Atlassian stash doesn't support git notes natively but notes are so useful for things like bug tracking, logging build results and so on that it boggles my mind there's no official support for it.

Has anyone written a plugin to provide at least rudimentary support for notes in Stash?  Ideally I'd like to be able to view notes attached to a commit and search for commits based on notes contents.

Comment: We have the same need for our company (because we are migrating from SVN to Git/Stash, and the SVN revisions are stored as Git Notes). We are trying to write our own plugin, but it's not ready for the moment...

Comment: That's exactly what we're using notes for as well.  If you do ever get a plugin going and put it in the marketplace, let us know here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of.

Support for git notes is recorded in [`STASH-2759`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2759) since October 2012.

> It would be useful if the commit screen showed any notes associated with a commit. It would be even better if one could configure (either at the system administration level or the user profile level) which notes namespaces are shown.
>   Another approach would be to show the default namespace notes by default and have a "show all notes" button to show everything else (equivalent to a `--show-notes=*`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an add-on for Bitbucket Server called "Tag Details And Notes" at the Atlassian Marketplace.
At Commits page and Pull Request page it adds a new column “Notes”. Commits with at least one note gets an icon in that column. Hover over it shows the full note(s).
The add-on also adds a “Notes” section to the Commit View page.
The add-on is for free. You can download it at: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jh.atlassian.stash.stash-tagdetails/server/overview